# How Do I Request an HTML View from a Controller in Java and not through a Web Browser using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, servlets

I am using Spring MVC.

In `Controller1` I return a `ModelAndView` of the current progress of an item that is being 'published'.  I am using Velocity as my view resolver if that makes any difference.  What is returned, is obviously, HTML.

What I want is `Controller2` and `Controller3` to make a call to `Controller1` and include the HTML view that `Controller1` returns along with the HTML view that they will return.

I only know how to call controllers through the web browser using a URL.  How do I call and receive HTML in java code?

If I can stick with just using the spring framework, that would be best.

I was reading about Spring's RestController, but I am unsure if I can return a ModelAndView using a view resolver?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just include the template of one velocity file in another?

Comment: All three Controllers are different applications on different servers.  I would either need to request the model from Controller1, or request the HTML.  I would rather request the HTML.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Aha. Now it kind of depends which parts of the HTML you want. If you just want it all, you can send an HTTP request to the server1 which will get handled by Controller1, get the HTML from its HTTP response and plug it in. If you only need parts of it, you'll need a more sophisticated parsing logic.

Comment: I would want it all - As in everything between <div> <!--Body--> </div>  I don't care about HTTP headers or all that extra stuff that goes along with http.  just the response body.

Comment: Then you need to parse the HTML content you receive in that http response and extract those parts.

Comment: Well, that's kinda the reason I asked the question.  I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Spring's RestTemplate is what I was looking for:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

Here is a link where it is used used.  Interesting part near the bottom:

http://dyutiman.wordpress.com/2010/12/09/simple-rest-web-service-spring/